# Importing whole NSArray to core data

Tags: xcode, core-data, for-loop, import, nsarray

I have UITextView, where user enter copied text, structured in lines:

Peter
Paul
Sonia
Edgar

Then I run script to store the text in lines in NSArray.
Finally, I want to import that array to core data, but it only imports the last object - EDGAR - why?

I have two functions - one to fill array and second to loop through the array and save context:

```
- (IBAction)saveArray:(id)sender {

if ([inputTV.text length] > 0) {

// --------- decrypt text

    NSString *importTxt = inputTV.text;
    NSMutableArray *importedText = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSCharacterSet *cs = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:importTxt];

    NSString *line;
    while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
        if ([scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:cs intoString:&line]) {
            NSString *copy = [NSString stringWithString:line];
            NSLog(@"copy: %@",copy);
            [importedText addObject:copy];
            //[newManagedObject setValue:copy forKey:@"name"];
        }
    }
//------------ save it to an array

    newArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:importedText];
    NSLog(@"Array: %@", [newArray description]);

}

//--------------- save to core data

[self saveToDatabase];

}

-(void)saveToDatabase{

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

for (int count = 0; count < [newArray count]; count ++){

    [newManagedObject setValue:[newArray objectAtIndex:count] forKey:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"for() function array object: %@", [newArray objectAtIndex:count]);

    // Save the context.

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"Save Succeeded");
    }

}

}
```

How can be the whole array imported to core data please?

I tried different methods, but it always saves the last object only:

```
NSEnumerator *e = [newArray objectEnumerator];
    id object;
    while (object = [e nextObject]) {
        NSLog(@"Enum: %@", object);
        [newManagedObject setValue:object forKey:@"name"];

    }
```

Or

```
for (NSString *object in newArray) {

       [newManagedObject setValue:object forKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"for loop: %@", object);
    }
```

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you save values to the same NSManagedObject. 
You need to insert a new one in the loop.

Comment: jeez, of course! An error between keyboard and chair! Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @Alessign It happens to all of us time to time :)